# How to add a secondary ip address permanently on fedora linux 25?

Tags: linux, configuration, linux-networking, fedora

Lots of examples out there to do this temporary, but can I make this secondary IP address permanent, so that it survives reboots "the fedora way", or does this really need some kind of non-standard script to make this work?
While this question (*) answers this partially, there a a lot of settings in the "ifcfg" scripts these days, like UUID, AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY and a lot of IPV_6 settings, which i do not need at this point.

So the question is really how to add a secondary ip adress properly without screwing up network settings ? I am worried that I will introduce some weird network behaviour of the machine if i just "copy" these values.

e.g. what do do with these values of the default "eth0" (copy them,  change them?)

```
UUID=5e14c1d3-a58a-4540-8a9d-107210cc45aa
AUTOCONNECT_PRIORITY=-999
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
```

(*) [Linux: how to configure a secondary IP address upon boot-up?](https://serverfault.com/questions/100280/linux-how-to-configure-a-secondary-ip-address-upon-boot-up)

Comment: First you should put a _primary_ IP address in there! Then [read this](http://serverfault.com/a/461536/126632).

Answer (score 2):

most of the values, like those you've mentioned, refer to the device itself. therefore, when configuring alias, they shouldn't be mentioned in the file at all.

it's a good practice to keep configuration files as minimal as possible. in your case, only `DEVICE, NAME, ONBOOT` and parameters referring to the IP address you want to add (such as `IPADDR` and `NETMASK`, etc.)